# Power BI changing decimal separator from comma to dot

Tags: powerbi, format, decimal, regional-settings

I have spent for 2 hours searching and testing how to change the current data which contains ',' to '.' as seperator in Power BI. But unfortunatly i havent found the solution.

the requirement is simple:
I would like to change the comma separator into dot seperator in my current table (see red arrows). Strange enough this doesnt work (as u can see) for amount that are higher then 1 million.

Here are the specs:

**The current data format type for field:**
Whole number

**The current custom format for these numbers is:**

#,##,.000

[image]

**So here are the steps which i have done to fix the issue:**

1. Changing the Windows Regional setting to '.':

[image]

2. Change the regional settings > Model languange > Dutch (Netherlands) on the Power BI Desktop and restart all apps:
   [image]

Any suggestions?

Kind regards